# Add spaces between characters of output from AI engine

Tags: python, bash

Getting some nice output from a Tron AI engine, but I'd like to change the format. I can't change the engine code, but I'd still like to change the ouput I get from standard out.

I get this:

```
##############################
#                            #
#                            #
#                            #
#                            #
#                            #
#                            #
#                            #
#                            #
#                            #
#   #####      #####         #
#  ######     ##   #####     #
#  #   ##     #    ##        #
#  ####    ####              #
#     #    #                 #
# ##########                 #
########2 ##                 #
##### ###                    #
#   1 ###                    #
##############################
```

It is a field of x=30 by y=20.

As you can see, it more looks like the opposite (due to newlines taking more space than horizontal space).

I was thinking perhaps I can pipe the output to something that adds a space after every non-newline character, that would be great.

So how can I use bash to add a space after every character (or alternatively, double each character)?

Other hacks to make this more look like 30x20 are also welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sed:

```
sed -e 's/./& /g'
```

Another option is to change the font to a wider one.